# What does standard C header boilerplate even do? From the Check testing framework tutorial

Tags: c

This thing

```
#ifndef MONEY_H
#define MONEY_H

#endif
```

in `src/money.h`. What is the purpose? I understand the `#ifndef` macro, but what do we define `MONEY_H` to? Why? This is taken from [the tutorial](https://libcheck.github.io/check/doc/check_html/check_3.html#Tutorial) to the popular Check testing framework. Assuming the autotools setup, not cmake. I've been reading automake, autoconf, and make GNU documentation, and reading that slidedeck everybody recommends, and it cleared many things up about the project structure and layout. But I'm still overwhelemed by the amount of new information and things like these confuse me.

Comment: Do a search for *header include guard*.

Comment: What I really wanted was to received a better tutorial. This one is bad. Why on earth do we define an empty identifier MONEY_H?

Comment: You *have* searched and read about [*include guards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), and possibly about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) as well? Then it should be obvious why the macro definition is needed (or a [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)).

Comment: Additionally, this is a standard C idiom.  It has nothing in particular to do with check-framework except inasmuch as that may *use* the idiom.  It is furthermore not GNU-specific, and has nothing at all to do with the Autotools.  (Tags edited.)

Answer (score 1):

This is used to avoid double inclusion of your .h file, so that, if the .h is already included, you doesn't include it again